Forward user to Stripe to get card details using only PHP
The scenario is, we have a marketplace platform, where sellers can sell their products to the buyers. Using Stripe connected Express accounts for the sellers with Stripe's onboarding process, and store only the responded account_id in our databse.
We have to hold back the money for a few days, so we have to create a PaymentIntent(), which responses a client_secret.
Is there a PHP solution and example code to forward the buyers to stripe to handle the card payment?

the easiest way to get started is to use Stripe checkout to create charges directly on the connected account (through Direct Charges), or on platform first and then transfer to connected account (through Destination Charges).
You can also use manual payouts if you don't want Stripe to automatically send payouts to your users.
